# Bulk Insert - (0 row(s) affected)

Tags: sql-server, errors, csv, bulk-insert

I am trying to import a .CSV file into a mssql table using bulk insert (Although I am open to other methods). I have a bulk insert sql statement but it says (0 row(s) affected) when I execute the the file. However, I have data in the file itself.

Sample CSV File (Header + One Line below header)

---

**.CSV Header**

> changedate,deactivate,lockout,noemail,empno,orighire,salary,salut,fname,mi,lname,username,hstreet1,hstreet2,hcity,hstate,hcountry,hzip,busphone,busext,cellular,empemail,jobtitle,jobcode,jobgroup,orglevel1,orglevel2,orglevel3,orglevel4,orglevel5,company,perfdate,supervisor,misc1,misc2,misc3,misc4,active

**.CSV Content**

> 2014-04-03 00:00:00,NO ,NO ,NO ,1133,2014-04-03 00:00:00,1111.1111,,test,test,test,user.test,111 test way,,Sacramento,CA,USA,11111,,,,test@test.org,test test,057,02,sss,261,SAC,,test,ttt,1911-11-11 00:00:00,1111,N,,test,0,NULL

---

**.SQL**

```
BULK
INSERT dbo.Archive
FROM 'C:\scripts\User.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n',
FIRSTROW = 2
)
GO
```

**I tried to achieve this through ps and this was the outcome and code:**

```
# Database variables
$sqlserver = "dbserver"
$database = "db"
$table = "tb"

# CSV variables
$csvfile = "C:\scripts\User.csv"
$csvdelimiter = ","
$firstRowColumnNames = $true

################### No need to modify anything below ###################
Write-Host "Script started..."
$elapsed = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew() 
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data")
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.SqlClient")

# 50k worked fastest and kept memory usage to a minimum
$batchsize = 50000

# Build the sqlbulkcopy connection, and set the timeout to infinite
$connectionstring = "Data Source=$sqlserver;Integrated         Security=true;Initial Catalog=$database;"
$bulkcopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($connectionstring, [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::TableLock)
$bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = $table
$bulkcopy.bulkcopyTimeout = 0
$bulkcopy.batchsize = $batchsize

# Create the datatable, and autogenerate the columns.
$datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

# Open the text file from disk
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($csvfile)
$columns = (Get-Content $csvfile -First 1).Split($csvdelimiter)
if ($firstRowColumnNames -eq $true) { $null = $reader.readLine() }

foreach ($column in $columns) { 
$null = $datatable.Columns.Add()
}

# Read in the data, line by line
while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)  {
$null = $datatable.Rows.Add($line.Split($csvdelimiter))
$i++; if (($i % $batchsize) -eq 0) { 
    $bulkcopy.WriteToServer($datatable) 
    Write-Host "$i rows have been inserted in $($elapsed.Elapsed.ToString())."
    $datatable.Clear() 
} 
} 

# Add in all the remaining rows since the last clear
if($datatable.Rows.Count -gt 0) {
$bulkcopy.WriteToServer($datatable)
$datatable.Clear()
}

# Clean Up
$reader.Close(); $reader.Dispose()
$bulkcopy.Close(); $bulkcopy.Dispose()
$datatable.Dispose()

Write-Host "Script complete. $i rows have been inserted into the database."
Write-Host "Total Elapsed Time: $($elapsed.Elapsed.ToString())"
# Sometimes the Garbage Collector takes too long to clear the huge datatable.
[System.GC]::Collect()
```

**ERROR**

> PS C:\scripts> C:\scripts\Import-CSVtoSQL.ps1
>   Script started...
>   Exception calling "WriteToServer" with "1" argument(s): "Received an invalid column length from the bcp 
>   client for colid 38."
>   At C:\scripts\Import-CSVtoSQL.ps1:51 char:2
>   +     $bulkcopy.WriteToServer($datatable)
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the table I'm trying to import to, I have columns that are extra. i.e: `Datestamp`, `batch number`. Having more in the table than the csv file must be the issue. I imported to a temp table that has only the columns defined in the csv and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

The original question had `\n\r` as the row terminator. On Windows, a row terminator is typically `\r\n`, with the carriage return first and the linefeed second (for obscure but interesting historical reasons).  Try that in your `BULK INSERT` command.

Next, I would next try loading the file in a hex editor to validate the exact content of the line breaks.  For example, if the data is Unicode you may need `\0\r\0\n` as a separator, and/or the `DATAFILETYPE ='widechar'` flag. Note `0x0A` is decimal 10, `0x0D` is decimal 13: the ASCII codes for line feed (`\n`) and carriage return (`\r`), respectively.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `ERRORFILE = 'file_name'` to your with clause and see if an answer presents itself. (or an error at least.)
Usually it will run up to `MAXERRORS` errors and stop even if there are good lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Create a temp table, whether session-, instance-, or schema-based, to capture the data; **or**
- Create a view that simply contains the columns that will map 1-1.

#### Best solution

Have a table with all the living and meta data you need for the records:

```
CREATE TABLE [STAGE].[File](
    [RowID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AUDIT_BatchUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [FileID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [RowData] [varchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Create a view of that table with only the fields you need to be "recipients" of the data from the file.

```
CREATE VIEW [STAGE].[vw_File]
AS
SELECT        RowData
FROM            STAGE.[File]
```

`Bulk Insert` into the View. Mine happens to be dynamic SQL-based but the idea is there.

```
declare @stmt varchar(max)
select @stmt = '
    bulk insert stage.vw_File
    from ''' + @fileandpath + '''
    with (
        FirstRow = ' + @firstRow + ',
        RowTerminator = ''' + @rowTerminator + '''
    )
'
```

Sanitize the table data with the appropriate meta-data after the bulk insert.

Answer (score 0):

Something that can block the import is also a too short field in the destination : for instance, a field of 50 characters, while there are 51 characters in the source. But in fact you will get a message for each line, telling about an invalid character (not really explicit I feel).